# Binomial coefficient modulo 142857

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to calculate binomial coefficient modulo 142857 for large `n` and `r`. Is there anything special about the 142857? If the question is modulo `p` where `p` is prime then we can use Lucas theorem but what should be done for 142857.

Comment: Note that the factorisation helps because you can use CRT and compute the coefficient modulo 11, 13, 27 and 37.

Comment: Wikipedia links to a PDF about [Binary coefficients modulo prime powers](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf)

Comment: I implemented that prime powers algo and it is giving correct answer when power=1 but when power!=1 it is giving wrong answer for some inputs and correct for some. something wrong with my code i guess.

Comment: For anyone who's interested: [here](https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/number_theory.cpp#L162) is my implementation of a `binomod` function which was accepted during the contest. I used it together with the `crt_coprime` function in the same file.

Answer (score 14):

The algorithm is:

- factorise the base into prime powers; 142857 = 3^3×11×13×37
- compute the result modulo each prime power
- combine the results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

---

To compute `(n above k) mod p^q`:

Source: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf, theorem 1

define `(n!)_p` as the product of numbers `1..n` that are not divible by `p`

define `n_j` as `n` after erasing `j` least significant digits in base `p`

define `r` as `n`-`k`

define `e_j` as the number of carries when adding `k+r`, not counting the carries from `j` lowest digits, computing in base `p`

define `s` as `1` if `p=2 & q>=3` and `-1` otherwise

then `(n above k) mod p^q := p^e_0 * s^e_(q-1) * concatenate(j=d..0)( (n_j!)_p / ((k_j!)_p*(r_j!)_p) )` with each term of the concatenation computing one base-p digit of the result, lowest `j` computing the least significant non-zero digits.

Comment: I wonder how fast this is. Have you tried coding it? I'd like to compare it with my answer factorizing `n`.

Comment: @ThomasAhle I haven't tried implementing it, but if you're going to compute factorial of a number larger than a few hundred, you are going to wait a while.

Comment: The binomial is `product [(k+1)..n]/product [1..(n-k)]`, so you still need division, which you can't do modulo an arbitrary number. That's the whole point of this question, isn't it?

Answer (score 14):

You can actually calculate `C(n,k) % m` in `O(n)` time for arbitrary `m`.

The trick is to calculate `n!`, `k!` and `(n-k)!` as prime-power-vectors, subtract the two later from the first, and multiply the remainder modulo `m`. For `C(10, 4)` we do this:

```
10! = 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^1
 4! = 2^3 * 3^1
 6! = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^1
```

Hence

```
C(10,4) = 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^1 * 7^1
```

We can calculate this easily `mod m` as there are no divisions. The trick is to calculate the decomposition of `n!` and friends in linear time. If we precompute the primes up to `n`, we can do this efficiently as follows: Clearly for each even number in the product `1*2*...*9*10` we get a factor of `2`. For each fourth number, we get a second on and so forth. Hence the number of `2` factors in `n!` is `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...` (where `/` is flooring). We do the same for the remaining primes, and because there are `O(n/logn)` primes less than `n`, and we do `O(logn)` work for each, the decomposition is linear.

In practice I would code it more implicit as follows:

```go
func Binom(n, k, mod int) int {
    coef := 1
    sieve := make([]bool, n+1)
    for p := 2; p <= n; p++ {
        // If p is not sieved yet, it is a prime number
        if !sieve[p] {
            // Sieve of Eratosthenes
            for i := p*p; i <= n; i += p {
                sieve[i] = true
            }
            // Calculate influence of p on coef
            for pow := p; pow <= n; pow *= p {
                cnt := n/pow - k/pow - (n-k)/pow
                for j := 0; j < cnt; j++ {
                    coef *= p
                    coef %= mod
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return coef
}
```

This includes a Sieve of Eratosthenes, so the running time is `nloglogn` rather than `n` if the primes had been precalculated or sieved with a faster sieve.

Answer (score 3):

What's special about 142857 is that 7 * 142857 = 999999 = 10^6 - 1. This is a factor that arises from Fermat's Little Theorem with a=10 and p=7, yielding the modular equivalence 10^7 == 10 (mod 7). That means you can work modulo 999999 for the most part and reduce to the final modulus by dividing by 7 at the end. The advantage of this is that modular division is very efficient in representation bases of the form 10^k for k=1,2,3,6. All you do in such cases is add together digit groups; this is a generalization of [casting out nines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

This optimization only really makes sense if you have hardware base-10 multiplication. Which is really to say that it works well if you have to do this with paper and pencil. Since this problem recently appeared on an online contest, I imagine that's exactly the origin of the question.

Comment: 999999 is not really a more preferrable modulus to work with than 142857, so I don't see how this makes the problem easier to solve... You'll need Granville anyway

Comment: @NiklasB. You can do the calculations by hand easier. I don't think I ever said this made a software implementation better.

Comment: But the question was how the value could be computed? And in that context, there's nothing special about 142857 at all

Comment: This question was asked: "Is there anything special about the 142857?" That's the question I answered.