# how to calculte nCr % m

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

Provided that `m` is `not prime` how to calculate `nCr` ?

`1 <= n, r <= 100000`

Like if we have `m` prime, we can do is `fact(n) * invmod(fact(r)) * invmod(fact(n-r))`

where `invmod(a) = power(a, m-2)`

What to do if `m` is not prime ?

Comment: You can efficiently compute modular inverses using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: The answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106587/binomial-coefficient-modulo-142857). The question is less general but the answer works for you too.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - if m is not prime, then some numbers don't have a modular inverse.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

```
C(n,r) = fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))
```

But consider C(7,5):

```
C(7,5) = 7x6x5x4x3x2x1 / (5x4x3x2x1 * 2x1)
       = 7x6 / 2x1
```

So imagine that instead of doing all the products, we just did this with sets of values:

```
C(7,5) = product( set(1..7) - set(1..5) ) / product(1..2)
```

But in fact we could define a cross-cancellation function which took the items in one set and cancelled values from a second set where possible:

```
crossCancel(numeratorSet, denominatorSet) -> 
   remainingNumers, remainingDenoms
```

This should leave us with the minimal product which needs calculating modulo m, but we can go further. If we split each of the remaining items into its factors:

```
  7x6 / 2
= 7x3x2 / 2
```

A further reduction cancels the 2s

```
= 7x3
```

In reality, we know that nCr involves cancelling the common product (5x4..1) every time, so we can immediately shorten it to

```
product(set(r+1..n))/product(set(1..n-r))
```

Also it can be shown that the denominator will always cancel into the numerator (because if r and n are separated by e.g. 3 then 3 will be in the denominator and 3 consecutive numbers will be in the numerator, so one must cancel), so we know that we can always do

```
product(set(factorsOf(r+1 .. n)) - set(1..n-r))
```

Given this now-limited product, it should be fairly straightforward to determine what the product modulo m should be.